# Copying S3 objects from one account to other using Lambda python

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm using boto3 to copy files from s3 bucket from one account to other. I need a similar functionality like aws s3 sync. Please see my code. My company has decided to 'PULL' from other S3 bucket (source account). Please don't suggest replication, S3 batch, S3 trigger Lambda..etc. We have gone through all these options and my management do not want to do any configuration at source side. Can you please review this code and let me know if this code works for thousands of objects. Source bucket has nearly 10000 objects. We will create this lambda function in destination account and create a cloudwatch event to trigger the lambda once in a day.

I am checking ETag so that modified files will be copied across when this function is triggered.

Edit: I simplified my code just to see pagination works. It's working if I don't add client.copy(). If I add this line in for loop after reading 3,4 objects it's throwing "errorMessage": "2021-08-07T15:29:07.827Z 82757747-7b72-4f29-ae9f-22e95f969d6c Task timed out after 3.00 seconds". Please advise. Please note that 'test/' folder in my source bucket has around 1100 objects.

```py
import os
import logging
import botocore

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(os.getenv('debug_level', 'INFO'))

client = boto3.client('s3')
def handler(event, context):
    main(event, logger)

def main(event, logger):
    try:
        SOURCE_BUCKET = os.environ.get('SRC_BUCKET')
        DEST_BUCKET = os.environ.get('DST_BUCKET')
        REGION = os.environ.get('REGION')
        prefix = 'test/'
        # Create a reusable Paginator
        paginator = client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
        print ('after paginator')
        # Create a PageIterator from the Paginator
        page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket=SOURCE_BUCKET,Prefix = prefix)
        print ('after page iterator')
        index = 0
        for page in page_iterator:
            for obj in page['Contents']:
                index += 1
                print ("I am looking for {} in the source bucket".format(obj['ETag']))
                copy_source = {'Bucket': SOURCE_BUCKET, 'Key': obj['Key']}
                client.copy(copy_source, DEST_BUCKET, obj['Key'])
        logger.info("number of objects copied {}:".format(index))
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
        raise
```

Comment: It might have problems with more than 1000 objects in either bucket, since that is the maximum number of objects returned by `list_objects_v2()`. You should paginate the results, or use a [paginator](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Paginator.ListObjectsV2). The `if not excluded_dir in obj['Key']` might cause a problem on a partial match of a string -- better to compare with `.startswith()` rather than `in`.

Comment: Also, if an object has been copied under a different name, it will not be re-copied. For example, if object1 also exists as object2, only one of the objects will be copied.

Comment: Thanks John. I will try paginator. If possible can you point me where should I change my code. I didn't quite understand your second comment.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, I am testing this code in my development account with only few files, is there anyway to test this code with 1000s of objects?

Comment: Let's say you have an excluded directory called `s3copy/`. If an object was stored in `foo/bar/s3copy/something/`, then the `if not excluded_dir` line will stop the object being copied, simply because that directory name was _elsewhere_ in the path, not necessarily at the start of the path.

Comment: The best way to test it with 1000s of objects is to create 1000s of objects and run the code! You could just write a little script to create lots of objects. Sometimes I just create an Excel spreadsheet with a command (eg `aws s3 cp s3://bucket/file s3://bucket/file2`) and increment the number in each line. Then, copy and paste those commands into the shell to create lots of objects.

Comment: thanks @JohnRotenstein for the nice idea. I have created a simple shell script with for loop.

Answer (score 0):

This version is working fine if I increase the Lambda timeout to 15 min and memory to 512MB. This checks if the source object already exists in destination before copying.

```py
import boto3
import os
import logging
import botocore
from botocore.client import Config

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(os.getenv('debug_level', 'INFO'))

config = Config(connect_timeout=5, retries={'max_attempts': 0})
client = boto3.client('s3', config=config)

#client = boto3.client('s3')
def handler(event, context):
    main(event, logger)

def main(event, logger):
    try:
        DEST_BUCKET = os.environ.get('DST_BUCKET')
        SOURCE_BUCKET = os.environ.get('SRC_BUCKET')
        REGION = os.environ.get('REGION')
        prefix = ''
        # Create a reusable Paginator
        paginator = client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
        print ('after paginator')

        # Create a PageIterator from the Paginator
        page_iterator_src = paginator.paginate(Bucket=SOURCE_BUCKET,Prefix = prefix)
        page_iterator_dest = paginator.paginate(Bucket=DEST_BUCKET,Prefix = prefix)
        print ('after page iterator')
        index = 0
        for page_source in page_iterator_src:
            for obj_src in page_source['Contents']:
                flag = "FALSE"
                for page_dest in page_iterator_dest:
                    for obj_dest in page_dest['Contents']:
                        # checks if source ETag already exists in destination
                        if obj_src['ETag'] in obj_dest['ETag']:
                            flag = "TRUE"
                            break
                    if flag == "TRUE":
                        break
                if flag != "TRUE":
                    index += 1
                    client.copy_object(Bucket=DEST_BUCKET, CopySource={'Bucket': SOURCE_BUCKET, 'Key': obj_src['Key']}, Key=obj_src['Key'],)
                    print ("source ETag {} and destination ETag {}".format(obj_src['ETag'],obj_dest['ETag']))
                    print ("source Key {} and destination Key {}".format(obj_src['Key'],obj_dest['Key']))
        print ("Number of objects copied{}".format(index))
        logger.info("number of objects copied {}:".format(index))
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
        raise
```